# System argument exception no app provided for key

Tags: c#, app-config, configurationmanager

I have a C# program which generates CSV reports.
I don't have the source code, but I used dotPeek for decompiling the code.

When I started program, I had exception:

> System.ArgumentException: No app config provided for key
>   [radioopt.qosextractor.export.filter.atm_os_versions]

I have the same names of exe file and configuration file and I have `System.Configuration` in the references and it uses `ConfigurationManager` :

```
private static void ReadAtmOsVersions()
{
  string appSetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["radioopt.qosextractor.export.filter.atm_os_versions"];
  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(appSetting))
    throw new ArgumentException("No app config provided for key radioopt.qosextractor.export.filter.atm_os_versions.");
  string path = appSetting.Trim();
  if (!File.Exists(path))
    throw new ArgumentException("Could not open config file " + path + ".");
  foreach (string readAllLine in File.ReadAllLines(path))
  {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(readAllLine))
    {
      string str1 = readAllLine.Trim();
      if (!str1.StartsWith("//") && !str1.StartsWith("#"))
      {
        if (str1.Contains("//"))
          str1 = str1.Substring(0, str1.IndexOf("//"));
        string str2 = str1.Trim();
        if (str2.Length > 0)
        {
          if (stringBuilder.Length == 0)
            stringBuilder.Append(" { ");
          else
            stringBuilder.Append(",");
          stringBuilder.Append("  \r\n [Devices].[OSVersion].&[" + str2 + "]");
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (stringBuilder.Length > 0)
    stringBuilder.Append("  \r\n } ");
  QoSConstants.ConfigFilter_FormattedOsVersionList = stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Config file:

```
<!-- Files are dumpped locally first. -->
<add key="radioopt.qosextractor.export.dir.local" value=".\\export\\"/>   
<!-- If the .final key exists the result (zip file) is copied to the folder given in the .final key -->
<add key="radioopt.qosextractor.export.dir.final" value=".\\final"/>

<!-- Number of recent csv exports to be put into the zip file (default = 4) -->
<add key="radioopt.qosextractor.export.zip.filecount" value="4"/> 

<!-- In case the zip file shall be password protected -->
<!-- <add key="radioopt.qosextractor.export.zip.pwd" value="123456" /> -->

<!-- Config file providing the whitelist of ATM OS versions -->
<add key="radioopt.qosextractor.export.filter.atm_os_versions" value="filter_atm_os_versions.txt"/>

<!-- Config file providing the whitelist of countries -->
<add key="radioopt.qosextractor.export.filter.countries" value="filter_countries.txt"/>
```

Comment: Just to clarify the code which uses this library and config file, are they both in the same assembly? Have you tried manually to get this app setting to check that you have access to config file?

Comment: can u tell us what is the name of the config file name?

Comment: They both in the same assembly, because it worked and it has been working on another computer, this program is used by company now, and i'm rewriting this program on Java.
The name of config file: "filter_atm_os_versions.txt"
File hierarchy: [link](https://imgur.com/a/lPRGt)